# Convert JSON data into the PDF in tabular format?

Tags: jquery, pdf

How we can convert the following `JSON data` into the `PDF tabular format` using **Jquery** ? Cab we provide button which will render data in **PDF**?

Any help for converting this into **PDF**? I am new to the jquery, not sure how we can do that ?

```
[
    {
        "file": "C:\\FI\\POC_FI\\LightningExamples\\Circular Progress Bar\\CircularProgress\\CircularProgressHelper.js",
        "result": [
            {
                "ruleId": "radix",
                "severity": 2,
                "message": "Missing radix parameter.",
                "line": 15,
                "column": 44,
                "nodeType": "CallExpression",
                "source": "        if(totalVal && actualVal && !isNaN(parseInt(totalVal)) && isFinite(totalVal) && !isNaN(parseInt(actualVal)) && isFinite(actualVal)){"
            },
            {
                "ruleId": "radix",
                "severity": 2,
                "message": "Missing radix parameter.",
                "line": 15,
                "column": 96,
                "nodeType": "CallExpression",
                "source": "        if(totalVal && actualVal && !isNaN(parseInt(totalVal)) && isFinite(totalVal) && !isNaN(parseInt(actualVal)) && isFinite(actualVal)){"
            },
            {
                "ruleId": "radix",
                "severity": 2,
                "message": "Missing radix parameter.",
                "line": 17,
                "column": 27,
                "nodeType": "CallExpression",
                "source": "            var percVal = parseInt(actualVal) / parseInt(totalVal) ;"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\FI\\POC_FI\\LightningExamples\\Responsive Grid\\DataGrid\\DataGridHelper.js",
        "result": [
            {
                "ruleId": "default-case",
                "severity": 2,
                "message": "Expected a default case.",
                "line": 21,
                "column": 13,
                "nodeType": "SwitchStatement",
                "source": "            switch(currentTag.getDef().getDescriptor().getName()){"
            },
            {
                "ruleId": "no-console",
                "severity": 2,
                "message": "Unexpected console statement.",
                "line": 48,
                "column": 21,
                "nodeType": "MemberExpression",
                "source": "                    console.log('Detected Iteration tag');"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\FI\\POC_FI\\LightningExamples\\Responsive Grid\\ResponsiveDatagridWrapper\\ResponsiveDatagridWrapperController.js",
        "result": []
    },
    {
        "file": "C:\\FI\\POC_FI\\LightningExamples\\Responsive Grid\\ResponsiveDatagridWrapper\\ResponsiveDatagridWrapperHelper.js",
        "result": [
            {
                "ruleId": "no-alert",
                "severity": 2,
                "message": "Unexpected alert.",
                "line": 34,
                "column": 21,
                "nodeType": "CallExpression",
                "source": "                    alert('Error in Component - '+errors[0].message);"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Answer (score -1):

you might wanna take a look at pdf.js. and there is also an additional package which will add table support.

Look here

https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable

I used this for a project in the past and it rendered pretty well. You'll still have to put in a little work in the code to get the data from your json out though.

[edit]

If its a string and needs to pe parsed first. JSON.parse(yourString). If it's already a JSON you can directly start. With the jsPDFAutotable it would look similar to this

```
var columns = ['RuleID', 'Severity', 'Message'....];
var rows = [];
$.each(yourJSON, function(){
   $.each(this.result, function(){
      rows.push([this.ruleId, this.severity, this.message,...]);
   });
});

var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.autoTable(columns, rows);
doc.save('table.pdf');
```

[/edit]